# How to create event in google calender using php

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I have try to create event in google calnder using php.But it not reflected in google.

I follow this code

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/how_to_start.html

in data.php file have this code

```
include('../src/google_proxy.php');

$calendar = new GoogleCalendarProxy(
    "878294925469@developer.gserviceaccount.com",    // email from Google API console
    "878294925469.apps.googleusercontent.com",   // user id from Google API console
    file_get_contents("./AIzaSyBvNVHdRZJ33lCKiGSuRWMEEd1liasGJ7A"),                         // private key
    "35hnoajpn21hmjtk27s7rnc77g@group.calendar.google.com"  // calendar id
);
```

i have the api console account ,in that account have only client id and Client secret .

I dont know how to get these2 values   "878294925469@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
        "878294925469.apps.googleusercontent.com.

how to post and get the event.

can any one suggest better code for google calender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download google calender code from this link

http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/dhtmlxscheduler-synchronization-with-google-calendar/